# Trying to add title to attribute to a link (from a widget) by targeting parent classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, title

I am trying to add a title attribute to a link "more infos"
my code is here
https://codepen.io/Gerald-Mardirossian/pen/vYxQyNB
My js / jquery is working on the first link "->jQuery Mandatory" but not on the link "more infos"

any idea why ?

js code :

$('.jmandatoryz a').attr('title', 'sfudifhtitel');

working

and

$('.Card-sc-1ib64vn-0 a').attr('title', 'Covid widget');

not working / I don't know why

thank you for your help

Comment: Try like this :  `$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.Card-sc-1ib64vn-0 > a').attr('title', 'Covid widget'); })`

Comment: I think, it is not working (unless I am not doing it right ? ) https://codepen.io/Gerald-Mardirossian/pen/YzZRZad

Comment: Hi, put that script in last after your `<script type="text/javascript">$('#widget a')...` see if that works .